# Bootstrap row won't break up

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have it so the row breaks up when it reaches the bottom of the div box however, it isn't doing it. I am using Bootstrap 3.

```
    <div class="col-md-10 column" id="main">
        <h3>
          Gallery
        </h3>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <ul> 
                        <li class="span4"><img src="img/thumbs/6.jpg" alt=""</li>
                        <li class="span4"><img src="img/thumbs/7.jpg" alt=""</li>
                        <li class="span4"><img src="img/thumbs/8.jpg" alt=""</li>
                        <li class="span4"><img src="img/thumbs/9.jpg" alt=""</li>
                        <li class="span4"><img src="img/thumbs/11.jpg" alt=""</li>
                        <li class="span4"><img src="img/thumbs/12.jpg" alt=""</li>
                        <li class="span4"><img src="img/thumbs/19.jpg" alt=""</li>
                        <li class="span4"><img src="img/thumbs/20.jpg" alt=""</li>

                </div>
            </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: You are using a mix of Bootstrap 2 and Bootstrap 3 classes. Choose one or the other. .row-fluid, .spanX are not classes in Bootstrap 3. Please read docs, look at examples, and check out .list-inline.

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3. In that case what should I replace the span with. I am completely stuck at the moment.

Comment: Look at the docs. GetBootstrap.com

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: @MatthewWilson, what do you mean breaks?  Can you include a simple wireframe of what you would expect to happen at a couple different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the [Documentation for the Bootstrap 3 grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and really work through some of the examples to make sure you understand that.

Here is a runnable snippet of your current markup:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <ul> 
      <li class="span4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1" alt=""/></li>
      <li class="span4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=2" alt=""/></li>
      <li class="span4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=3" alt=""/></li>
      <li class="span4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=4" alt=""/></li>
      <li class="span4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=5" alt=""/></li>
      <li class="span4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=6" alt=""/></li>
      <li class="span4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=7" alt=""/></li>
      <li class="span4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=8" alt=""/></li>
      </ul>
  </div> 
</div>
```

If you just want each of the images to take up 4 out of 12 columns at all screen sizes you can use `.col-xs-4`, but without more info as to what you're expecting to achieve, it would be hard to say for sure what you need to do.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=2" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=3" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=4" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=5" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=6" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=7" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=8" alt=""/></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```